# Prove KL Divergence $\displaystyle \int_{\chi}p(\textbf x) \text{log}\frac{p(\textbf x)}{q\left(\textbf x, V\right)}d\textbf x$ is Convex w.r.t. V

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations, information-theory

**Problem**: I have two kernel density estimates of distributions, call these $p(\textbf x)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{|X|} \sum_{\textbf x_i \in X} K_H(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_i)$ and $q(\textbf x)=\frac{1}{|W \cup V|}\displaystyle  \sum_{\textbf x_i \in W} K_H(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_i)+\textstyle\frac{1}{|W \cup V|}\displaystyle\sum_{\textbf v_i \in V} K_H(\textbf{x}-\textbf{v}_i)$, which is basically an average of two kernel densities on different sets $W$ and $V$.

I want to show that the KL Divergence between these two, i.e. $\displaystyle \int_{\chi}p(\textbf x) \text{log}\frac{p(\textbf x)}{q(\textbf x)}d\textbf x$, is convex with respect to the set $V$ in q, fixing all the other points.

In this light, we can rewrite $q$ as a function of $\textbf x$ and $V$, $q\left(\textbf x, V\right)$, and the integral becomes $\displaystyle \int_{\chi}p(\textbf x) \text{log}\frac{p(\textbf x)}{q\left(\textbf x, V\right)}d\textbf x$, which implicitly defines a function in terms of $V$, $F(V)$. Then, I need to show that that implicit function is convex.

It could be as simple arguing that since KL divergence is convex, then whatever form $q$ takes it is convex, therefore it is convex with respect to the parameter $V$ that defines $q$. Is that a correct argument?

What about variational calculus? I could describe the problem as minimizing the integral with respect to the function $q(\textbf x, V)$ defined by the set $V$. Then, taking the Euler-Lagrange equation:

$\frac{\delta J}{\delta q}=- \frac{p(\textbf x)}{q(\textbf x,V)}$ and $\frac{\delta^2 J}{\delta q^2}=\frac{p(\textbf x)}{q(\textbf x,V)^2} \geq 0 \space \forall V$ as they are PDFs so always greater than 0, and therefore for any $V$ it is convex (second derivative always greater than 0). Can it be argued this way?

At the end of the day, the reason I need this is to support the argument that if we have a set of candidate points $G$, iteratively picking the point and adding it to $q$ that gives the minimum KL divergence at each step (i.e. constructing a set $V$ greedily by picking the best (min KL divergence) point at each step and updating $q$) will give the overall best set $V \subseteq G$ that minimizes the KL divergence (greedily optimal implies globally optimal).

Comment: How is V+W defined? Are V and W related to X?

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, I should've been more clear about V+W, I just edited the question (should be union). V, W and X are just sets of points (say n-dimensional vectors) not necessarily related. W and X are fixed, V is variable (ie I can choose whatever points to add to it).

Comment: Your line of argumentation is incorrect. If $f$ is a convex function, this does not imply that $f \circ g$ is convex for any $g$ (take e.g. $f(x) = x$ and $g = \log(x)$).

Comment: @IljaKlebanov that's true in general, though in this case the second functional derivative with respect to $q$ is positive for any $q$ and $p$, so it is convex with respect to $q$. Since $q$ is defined by $V$, does it then follow that is is convex with respect to $V$? (Since for any $V$, it is still convex)

Comment: Let me add some more detail: Let $f(q) = KL(p||q)$ and $g(V) = q(\cdot,V)$, then you are arguing for the convexity of $f\circ g$ (as a function of $V$) based on the convexity of $f$ (as a function of $q$). This argument alone is not sufficient.

Comment: @IljaKlebanov I see, what would be a good next step in proving/disproving that argument?

Comment: @IljaKlebanov my (probably incorrect) argument was that the integral is convex in $q$ for any $V$, that means that there exists only one extrema, $q*$, defined by a unique $V*$, with no other local minima. But then, that implies that no other $V$ leads to a local minimum of the integral, since no other $q$, defined by $V$, leads to a local minimum. Therefore, it must be convex in $V$.

Comment: There are a few things to say here. First, having a unique (local or global) minimum does not imply convexity. Second, the unique minimum $q^{\ast}$ of $KL(p||q)$, when minimized over all possible q, will most like *not* be of the your form $q(\cdot,V)$. Third, if it happens to be of the form, $q^{\ast} = q(\cdot,V^{\ast})$, then this is a remarkable result. Now that I think about it, in your specific case, $KL(p||q)$ is minimized by $q^{\ast} = p$, so $p$ would have to be of that form. I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: On the other hand, if you minimize $KL(p||q(\cdot,V))$ in $V$, which is what  I suppose you are doing, then your result will not be the best possible $q^{\ast}$ altogether, but the best one from the parametric family, and it is unclear if this minimizer is unique (a priori). There might well be several different $V$ with the same value of $KL(p||q(\cdot,V))$. I don't have a simple solution. The straightforward way of writing out $KL(p||q(\cdot,V))$ and analyzing it as a function of $V$ (in terms of convexity etc.) seems tedious.